# Macro To Change Pivot Table Filters

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My goal is to change the filter of  3 pivot tables, all with the same field with the click of a button attached to a macro.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim pickedDate As String
    Dim shift As String

     pickedDate = Worksheets("Report").Range("C1").Value
    shift = Worksheets("Report").Range("C2").Value

    Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.SourceData = Worksheets("Fullness").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1, True)
    Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.SourceData = Worksheets("Backed").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1, True)
    Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.SourceData = Worksheets("Hoist").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1, True)


    For Each PT In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        PT.PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = CDate(pickedDate)
        PT.PivotFields("Shift").CurrentPage = shift
    Next
```

However when I get to my loop for the pivot tables, I get the error on `PT.PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = CDate(pickedDate)`
 :

`Run time error 1004`

`Application  Defined or Object Defined Error`

I've verfied the source data for the tables is updated correctly.

I've tried not using the loop, and doing it manually like

`Worksheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = CDate(pickedDate)`

for each table, and it only works for one of the tables, my `PivotTable3`.

Even more curiously, when I comment out my code to change the date, and use either way (the loop or the manual change for the 3 tables) for the shift change it works perfectly with no error.

I've verfied the name of my pivot tables, that's not the issue. The name of the field I'm trying to change appears correct as well- it works for one of the tables and I've copied and pasted that cell "Date" into the others even.

What am I missing?

Comment: blind guess - is this date present in the table?

Comment: @brainac Yes, it is. Although good point! I've made that mistake before, that's why I update the data source first in case there is a date that wasn't there before I'm trying to filter on later in the code

Comment: @brainac If you're interested in the solution, I've posted one, although honestly I'm not sure why it really made all the difference

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure why this works now, but all I did to change my code was add into the loop a clear filter command for the "Date" field.

So now my code has this loop instead for making the date and shift change for all the pivot tables based on a cell value I enter manually, just once

```
 For Each PT In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        PT.PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
        PT.PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = CDate(pickedDate)
        PT.PivotFields("Shift").CurrentPage = shift
    Next
```

Again, I'm not sure why I didn't have to do this for the shift filter, but now it works. I suggest trying that first if anyone encounters this issue